# Navigation dropdown background missing on mouseover

Tags: html, css

I am working on this site: http://www.problemio.com and if you mouse over the "categories" navigation item on top of the page, you will see a missing background.

Here is the css I use for it:

```
.menusystem 
{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
}

.menusystem ul, .menusystem li 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menusystem li 
{
    list-style: none outside none;
}

.menusystem ul 
{
    list-style: none;
}

.menusystem ul li ul 
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.6em;
    right: 0;
}

.menusystem li a 
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menusystem ul li.main_menu_li 
{
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 7px; 

    display: block;
    float:right;

    margin-right:0.2em;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: solid 1px white;   
/*  line-height: 1em;   */
    height: 15px;
}

.menusystem ul li.main_menu_li_left
{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 7px;    
    margin-bottom: 7px;     

    display: block;
    float:right;
    margin-right:0.2em;
    text-align: center;


/*  line-height: 1em;   */
    height: 15px;   
}

/* IE-Win (Holly hack) reads the list item line breaks, so lets hide those \*/
* html ul li { float: left; }
* html ul li a { height: 1%; }


.menusystem li:hover ul, .menusystem li.mouseHover ul { 
    display: block;
}

.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li a
{
    color: #fff;


    font-size: 80%;
    text-shadow: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e6ea4;
    border-top: 0px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2E6EA4;
}


.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li.first a
{
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 14px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #2e6ea4;
}


.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li.last a
{
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 14px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 14px;
}


.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li a:hover 
{
    color: #ff0;
    background: #2e6ea4; 
}

/*.menusystem li.main_menu_li a */
.menusystem ul.child_menu_ul a
{
    color: #fff;            
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

.menusystem li.main_menu_li a:hover 
{
    color: orange;
}
```

Could someone please tell me how to make the background some sort of brown or dark color? Thanks!

Comment: `.main_menu_li_left .child_menu_ul {background: brown;}`, but I'd assume that's not, in fact, what you're trying to accomplish since it's such an obvious fix. In the likely event that it's not, could you please specify which element to which you're trying to apply the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple. You just need to target the drop down menu `ul` and set a `background-color`:

```
.menusystem ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.6em;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #391C07; /* add this */
}
```

You can obviously change the hex code `#391C07` to whatever colour you would like to appear.